# Orbot works, but Tor doesn't

Tags: orbot, pluggable-transports, obfs4

I use Tor a lot at work because we have a strict firewall here.
Lately my Tor is not able to connect... but Orbot connects normally.

I don't know what I supposed have to do...

Obs.: Here just meek-azure works.

What should I do?

Log:

```
11/07/2016 09:46:17.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
11/07/2016 09:46:17.900 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
11/07/2016 09:46:21.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
11/07/2016 09:46:21.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
11/07/2016 09:47:21.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn; host B9E7141C594AF25699E0079C1F0146F409495296 at 0.0.2.0:2)
11/07/2016 09:47:21.400 [WARN] 1 connections have failed:
11/07/2016 09:47:21.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE
11/07/2016 09:47:23.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
11/07/2016 09:47:23.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
```

---- UPDATE ----
Data:

- There's no proxy here!
- Tor version 6.0.2
- Windows 10
- Company Firewall: Fortigate

[Using custom bridges]

```
12/07/2016 07:54:02.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.   
12/07/2016 07:54:02.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150   
12/07/2016 07:54:02.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server   
12/07/2016 07:54:02.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server   
12/07/2016 07:59:03.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150   
12/07/2016 07:59:03.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.   
12/07/2016 07:59:11.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150   
12/07/2016 07:59:58.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 6; recommendation warn; host B8839CDB805044D8360C989E6E9E121C081A662B at 146.0.73.3:443)   
12/07/2016 07:59:58.400 [WARN] 6 connections have failed:   
12/07/2016 07:59:58.400 [WARN]  3 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE   
12/07/2016 07:59:58.400 [WARN]  3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
```

[Using meek-azure]

```
12/07/2016 08:04:24.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150   
12/07/2016 08:05:28.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 7; recommendation warn; host A2C13B7DFCAB1CBF3A884B6EB99A98067AB6EF44 at 0.0.2.0:3)   
12/07/2016 08:05:28.800 [WARN] 7 connections have failed:   
12/07/2016 08:05:28.800 [WARN]  4 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE   
12/07/2016 08:05:28.800 [WARN]  3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)   
12/07/2016 08:05:44.000 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150   
12/07/2016 08:05:44.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.   
12/07/2016 08:05:44.000 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

IMPORTANT OBS: ORBOT works with this configuration, but Tor doesn't I don't know why (computer and cellphone are in the same LAN, same router, same ssid)

[Using Obsf4]

```
12/07/2016 08:06:47.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150   
12/07/2016 08:07:14.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to IP.AD.DD.RESS:443 ("general SOCKS server failure")
```

Obs.: I had to cancel because it took too much time!

Finally, all pluggable transports have fail.

Comment: Is Orbot set to use bridges? It looks like connections to the directory authorities are being blocked.

Comment: Yes, Orbot and Tor are using the same configuration (meek-azure) ... I will edit the post with more information!

Comment: Is it worth complaining about bridge addresses being posted in a public forum...?

Comment: My mistake, still learning. But, what about the problem itself?

Comment: Is it possible that your desktop and phone are receiving different treatment on the basis of their MAC address? Can you visit the meek "front" normally from your desktop? Also from what I can tell `0.0.2.0:2` is actually Meek-Amazon not Meek-Azure? Amazon: https://a0.awsstatic.com/ Azure: https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/

Comment: canonizing ironize there's no treatment based on MAC address here... I really don't know what I can do to be able to connect again. By the way, tecnologies like UltraSurf works.